# Bash shell question: Error occurs when running a simple shell script

Tags: linux, shell

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "helloworld"
```

I set the file mode to 755. when I try to run the script by typing "./test.sh", I get this:

```
helloworld
./test.sh: line 2: /root: is a directory
```

what's going on???

Comment: what happens when you do '/bin/bash -x ./test.sh; echo $?'

Comment: Are you redirecting the output? How exactly are you executing this? What user?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you are looking at the same `test.sh` as you are executing? `cat ./test.sh;./test.sh` would be interesting to see.

Comment: not redirecting output. I've tried root and a common user also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an exit and see

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "helloworld"
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd look for funny business in error/signal handlers and or the PROMPT_COMMAND

So,

```
echo $PS1
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
trap
```

would be in order.

Another approach is to make bash run restricted (which disables a whole slew of options)

```
#!/bin/bash -r
```

While the latter may resolve the strange behaviour, it wouldn't explain *waht* happened

Answer (score 0):

I guess edited from Windows/reused a Windows-file with an `\r` inside, which you moved around with inserting `exit`?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I accidentally put a ~ on the last line of my script while aiming for the escape key in vim. Because vim uses tildes to fill lines outside the file the mistake was nearly invisible. Removing the line containing the tilde got me rid of the

```
/root: Is a directory
```

error.